# why abstract class instantiation isn't runtime error in dart?

Tags: dart, abstract-class, abstract

In many languages if you try to instantiate abstract class you get compile time error.
In Dart however, you get warning while compiling and a runtime exception `AbstractClassInstantiationError`.

Why is that? Can someone provide an example, where it's reasonable to compile such code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dart tries to allow you to run your program while you are developing it.
That is why many things that are compile time errors in other languages are compile-time warnings and runtime errors in Dart. This includes "x is Foo" where Foo doesn't exist, type-annotating with a non-existing types, and calling constructors of partial (abstract) classes.

In short: because it's not a problem that prevents the program from being compiled (unlike a syntax error that might mean the rest of the file is interpreted wrongly), so there is no reason to stop you from running the code. Only if you hit the branch that actually depends on the problem will your program be stopped.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the answer is [factory constructor](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#factory-constructors) in abstract class:

```dart
abstract class Foo {
  factory Foo() { // make Foo appear to be instantiable
    return new Bar();
  }
  some(); // some abstract method
  Foo.name() {} just a named constructor
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  Bar():super.name(); // call named super constructor
  some() {} // implement abstract method
}

main() {
  print(new Foo()); // "instantiate" abstract Foo
}
```

Output:

```dart
Instance of 'Bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Asking 'where it's reasonable to compile such code?' in Dart isn't very meaningful because Dart is an interpreted language - there is no compilation stage. Dart editors will issue warnings if they think you are making a type error as they *analyse* your code on the fly.

Factory constructors can be used to provide a 'default' concrete implementation of an abstract class as you have done in your example. This is used quite widely in Dart. For instance, if you create a new `Map` object you actually get a `LinkedHashMap` object - see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930950/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-map-implementations-in-dart).

In your example your are not instantiating an instance of `Foo` ('new Foo' does not appear anywhere), you are instantiating a `Bar'. This is because when a factory constructor is called a new instance of its class is not automatically instantiated.

Comment: Dart is also a compiled language, due to dart2js compilation. In general, it doesn't always make sense to say that a *language* is compiled or interpreted, since you can usually do both, and many "interpreters" are really JIT-compilers behind the scene.

Comment: if you go to https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html and search for "compile" string you will get 18 results...

Comment: Point taken. I tend to regard compiling Dart to JS as a final code generation step, distinctly different from compiling Java to bytecode or C++ to object files.